# replacing content type field value in a view based on taxonomy term type in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-content-types, drupal-views-relationship

I have created a view which is displaying `content type fields` based on `taxonomy term` which is "Paid" and "Free".

I want to replace the text of `content type field` if the taxonomy term is "Paid" and I want to show different value for the `content type field` if it is "Free".

Is there a way to `views alter` by adding custom code.

I am just looking if this can be done in the `views` itself without using custom code.

Answer (score 0):

If i am right you want to create a Filter in `Views` to show what content to show on value `Paid` and `Free` . For this you can do

1. First create a `Content` with select option values as "Paid' and "Free" and mentioned text for `Paid` and `Free` as well.
2. Now create a `View` and put `Content type` as a `filter` in it in which you can choose value `Paid` or `Free` , now moment user select any value its get displayed as per the value.

Comment: hi the view will not be exposed to user and the condition should work inside the view itself without any hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php). With this module you could add a PHP field to your view and test the value `Paid` or `Free` to display what you want.

But as the module page says :

> While this module allows you to directly use PHP inside views which may be useful for quick and easy solutions, it is highly advisable to use regular handlers and plugins when available (or even to create one yourself).

Depending on your needs, you should consider writing a custom module or maybe rethink your implementation.

Comment: hi i know we can do this using custom module but i was just looking if this can be done inside the views itself.Regarding views php i know about this module but anyway thx for the info.

Comment: This part of your question is not very clear for me : Is there a way to views alter **by adding custom code**.
I am just looking if this can be done in the views itself **without using custom code**.

Comment: FYI the question is modified by someone without my approval .In the original question i haven't asked for custom code..

Comment: Ok, understood, the first sentence is not a question, it's "there is"